# Intercept Number 0 to 9 in Android EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, numbers

I want to intercept 0 to 9 button key events from soft keyboard in android. I have tried many ways but didn't succeed. any little help will help me a lot.

what I am doing is,

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {


    if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_12) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

in my custom EditText class but it is not working what am i missing? i have tried many key codes but no result in hand.

Comment: have you tried [dispatchKeyEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#dispatchKeyEvent%28android.view.KeyEvent%29) ?

Comment: what i want is when user press any number between 0 to 9, he/she won't be allowed to enter number in EditText.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a text watcher, its much simpler:

At Class level:

```
EditText editText;
```

in onCreate:

```
editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEdittext)

editText.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
```

Outside onCreate(Class level) :

```
final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher(){

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            System.out.println("Entered text: "+editText.getText());
                // USe edit_text.getText(); here 
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        };
```

If you want to restrict the entry on your Edit Text to only alphabets add this in the XML of your edit text control:

```
 android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

If you dont like the above and want to achieve this through code, use the following:

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence chr, int start,
                int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
            if(chr.equals("")){ 
                return chr;
            }
            if(chr.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")){
                return chr;
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can't use TextWatcher.i don't want user to allow enter number in EditText.

Comment: So use an if - else construct inside textWatcher

Comment: If you dont want user to enter a number in the editText it would be much simpler to specify your inputType in XML

Comment: I already used digits property. i works great in many devicec, but I have samsung galaxy tab 3. it is not working properly in this specific device. if i have entered "tgtg" in EditText and say if i press any number it will repeat the texts in EditText.

Comment: `if i press any number it will repeat the texts in EditText` please elaborate on that

Comment: say i have editext having text entered as "tgtg" now i press any number then automatically text entered into edittext will repeat itself.

Comment: Did you try the above solutions? In COde? Also go through [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType)

Comment: i am working on it. what is src here? edittext values?

Comment: Please use chr instead - it was a typing mistake.

Comment: ya i used. when i  type some text and then type any number edittext will be clear. why so? it should not be.

Comment: Please check and modify the return statements - no spoon feeding please!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Skynet. you saved lots of time of mine.